# Can't run Aptitude update: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/http could not be found

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, aptitude

When I run the "sudo aptitude update" I get the following output:

```
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/http could not be found.
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/http could not be found.
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/http could not be found.
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/http could not be found.
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/http could not be found.
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/http could not be found.
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/http could not be found.
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/http could not be found.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease: 
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease: 
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease: 
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease: 
W: Failed to fetch http://apt.galliumos.org/dists/xenon/InRelease: 
W: Failed to fetch http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu/dists/vs-xenial/InRelease: 
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease: 
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode/dists/stable/InRelease: 
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

And when I run "ls -la /usr/lib/apt/methods/http" I get this output:

```
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/apt/methods/http': No such file or directory
```

How do I fix this? I tried installing apt-transport-https which was recommended and it did nothing.

Comment: did you try "sudo apt install --fix-missing" or maybe "dpkg-reconfigure -a"

Comment: yeah but it returns "sudo: apt: command not found"

Comment: try apt-get or aptitude instead

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
sudo aptitude install --fix-missing
sudo aptitude update
```

if that doesn't work, try installing apt:

```
sudo aptitude install apt
sudo apt install --fix-missing
sudo apt update
```